# Effect of ignoring correlation between studies providing data for multiple comparison on the meta-estimate

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am addressing reviewer comments on a meta-analysis paper I performed on mean gastric pH in fed and fasted states.

Some literature studies included in the meta-analysis provided data for multiple comparisons (e.g under fed and fasted condition) as `study2` in the example data below while other studies provided data under only fed (`study1`) or fasted conditions (`study3`). The `metaphor` package in R treats the effect sizes obtained from studies provided data from multiple comparisons as an independent investigations (i.e. number of studies (k=4) and treats the same as studies with data obtained only under a single set of conditions (for example, study2 fed and fasted data may be correlated; however, the analysis ignores this correlation and treat data fed from `study2` the same way it does for data fed in `study1`).

My question: What potential impact ignoring this correlation might have on the meta-estimate of mean gastric pH?

```
   df <- 
   study   nsub   status   pH   vi
   study1    5    fed      5.0  0.10
   study2   10    fasted   2.0  0.02
   study2    8    fed      4.0  0.20
   study3    6    fasted   1.5  0.15


rma(yi = pH, vi = vi, data=df, method="REML", knha = TRUE, mods = ~factor(status)-1)

#Result
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 4; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.1591 (SE = 0.2709)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.3988
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 59.45%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   2.47

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 2) = 4.8039, p-val = 0.0905

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 1,2): 
F(df1 = 2, df2 = 2) = 79.1333, p-val = 0.0125

Model Results:

                      estimate      se     tval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub    
factor(status)fasted    1.8166  0.3475   5.2278  0.0347  0.3215  3.3117   *
factor(status)fed       4.5809  0.4003  11.4427  0.0076  2.8584  6.3034  **

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Why not use rma.mv and take the clustering into account?

Comment: @mdewey Would be my advice as well. Full example here: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for your input. I didn't actually know about the `rma.mv` function before. but I think it would be pain for me to re-do the meta-analysis again using `rma.mv` at this stage. But what are the possible implications if I didn't account for the correlation as I described in the question on the meta-estimates of the meta-mean and meta-SD of pH so I put it as a limitation in my study?

Comment: If you ignore the correlation you will get a misleading result (in general). Which is why the referee wants you to account for it and why @Wolfgang wrote <code>rma.mv</code>

Comment: @mdewey So, would the following be the correct way of doing it `rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ 1 | study, mods = ~factor(status)-1, method="REML", data=df)` ? I also noticed that `knha = TRUE` can't be used in `rma.mv` syntax

Comment: @Wolfgang I just wanted to confirm: would the following be the correct way of doing the meta-analysis for the example above: `rma.mv(yi=pH, V=vi, random = ~ 1 | study, mods = ~factor(status), method="REML", data=df)`? may be consider adding an answer?

Comment: @Amer No, please re-read the link I posted. Your `random` part is not sufficient.

Comment: @Wolfgang I re-read it and I am a bit confused actually. So this `rma(yi=pH, vi=vi, method="REML", mod=~factor(status), data=df)` is expected to give similar results to this `rma.mv(yi=pH, V=vi, method="REML", random = ~ 1 | study, mod=~factor(status), data=df)` but it doesn't in my case! And accounting for the correlation in studies reporting multiple comparisons would be this `rma.mv(yi=pH, vi, random = ~ 1 | study/status, mods = ~factor(status), method="REML", data=df)` ?

Comment: Your `study` variable is different than the one in the example. And yes to your question. But make sure that the assumption of independent sampling errors applies in your case. See: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011#uncorrelated_sampling_errors

Comment: @Wolfgang Here are some notes I thought to share with you. (1) RE model gives the exact same result to a multivariate model ONLY if the data has UNIQUE `study` number. i.e. this  `rma(yi=pH, vi=vi, method="REML", mod=~factor(status), data=df)` gives similar results to this  `rma.mv(yi=pH, V=vi, method="REML", random = ~ 1 | study, mod=~factor(status), data=df)` only when `df` has unique studies; which is not the case in the example above.

Comment: (2) This observation also relates to a question previously posted on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649678/meta-analysis-with-metafor-package-strange-difference-between-rma-and-rma-mv). I believe the data doesn't have a unique `RID` in that question and that is why he/she was getting different results by running the two models. @Wolfgang @JoachimMun

Comment: (3) In the example presented in the question: adding `study` and `fed` as factors in the multi-variate model gives exact similar results to RE model. i.e. this: `rma.mv(yi=pH, V=vi, method="REML", random = ~ 1 | study/status, mod=~factor(status), data=df)` gives similar results to this `rma(yi=pH, vi=vi, method="REML", mod=~factor(status), data=df)`

Comment: I am new to meta-analysis and was wondering does this mean that the fixed effects in the reported studies are not correlated?

Comment: I suspect the issue is that when you fit study/status you are effectively having one observation per level of the grouping variable.

Comment: @mdewey So in this case, it would mean that I will have an overparametarized model if I make grouping for both `study` and `status`. The likelihood profile for `sigma1` is not good. When I run the model on my actual data, large parts of the profile is flat. So, my conclusion, and I hope it is right, is to make grouping at the study level only. I would most welcome any other thoughts!

Comment: @Wolfgang Or perhaps an RE model in such case, when the model is overparameterized when grouping by study and status, may be satisfactory?